# Can't get syntax for deleting a commentable comment in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's the line from my routes config file:

```
DELETE  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)  posts/comments#destroy
```

I want to delete a single comment but I can't get the syntax right. Here's what I tried:

```
<% if current_user == comment.user %>
<span class="edit-delete-line"><p><small><%= link_to "Delete", post_comments_path([@commentable, comment]), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %> </span>
</small></p>

<% end %>
```

That gives me a routing error. I also tried:

```
<% if current_user == comment.user %>
<span class="edit-delete-line"><p><small><%= link_to "Delete", post_comments_path(params([:post_id], [:comment_id])), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %> </span>
</small></p>

<% end %>
```

I got "wrong number of argument" error this time. I know this should be simple, right???

Comment: Can you try use just `post_comments_path(@commentable, comment)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to delete a single comment, so you need to use `post_comment_path(@commentable, comment)`, not plural `post_comments_path`, which points at the `index`. If you have your controller set up to also accept the unnested resource (just `/comments/:id`), you can just use `comment_path` directly.

Check out the [Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guide for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= content_tag :span, link_to("Delete", [@commentable, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }), class: "edit-delete-line" if current_user == comment.user %>
```

This *should* get it working for you.

To give you a simple synopsis, you have to realize that the Rails routes are basically [*helper* methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) which are generated when you define your respective routes.

The route helpers themselves don't do anything except give you a dynamic way to call specific routes. For example, instead of `"/posts/<%= @post.id %>"`, you can call `posts_path(@post)`.

--

The Rails routes work very simply -- they take *arguments* like any other helper method.

Thus, if you call a route which requires specific values to be passed (for example `post_comments_path(post_id, comment_id)`, you have to pass the respective values to the helper.

Therefore, you can call the following:

```
post_comments_path(@commentable, comment), method: :delete
```

... or if you're using `link_to`, you *should* be able to pass the respective data objects that you require:

```
link_to "Destroy", [@commentable, comment], method: :delete
```